# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense squiggles for C code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 interprets C code as C++ and marks errors where they don't exist, as in:

```
struct my_struct *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
```

which is valid C, but not valid C++.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a known bug since at least MSVC 2005.  Unfortunately it has become a bigger issue in 2010 since VC now uses Intellisense to mark errors.

See [this discussion at the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcprerelease/thread/54995196-ab08-416d-9ddf-475bfb161779) for more information.  The following statement is disheartening, but I highly recommend that you add your voice to the conversation in the hopes that they may address the issue some day.

> I am just following up and let you know that we won't fix this bug in next VS release/update.
>
> If this bug affects your daily productivity severely, you can open/activate this bug with connect again.

Note that you can disable Intellisense's error reporting in Tools → Options... → Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced → Intellisense → Disable Error Reporting → True.  Of course, this really stinks if you're in a mixed solution or simply want to include an `extern "C"` header that throws Intellisense errors.

Comment: What about marking the entire code in an extern "C" block? Including the header files.

Comment: @Chris: Doesn't matter.  Intellisense pays no attention, and marches straight through it... which is a big problem if you have `extern "C"` headers with C++ "errors."