# Strange thing about pointers

Tags: c, visual-studio, pointers

I have some misunderstanding about VS C++. In version 2010 the code below works fine: I can get a string and I can free memory afterwords.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 #define MAX 14

 void GetString(char **str);

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    char *str = NULL;
    GetString(&str);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    getchar();

    free(str);

    return 0;
 }

 void GetString(char **str)
 {
    char *s = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
    strcpy(s, "HELLO, WORLD!");
    *str = s;
 }
```

But in VS 2008 the code above will end up with memory corruption error. I guess, there is a small difference in standards used. **Am I right? If no, could you, please, tell me, why the same code doesn't work in different versions of the Visual Studio?**

Thank you beforehand for your answers.

p.s. I'm curious of what happens, but couldn't yet find any information on the topic.

p.p.s. Language used - C

Comment: when giving code examples, make them compilable by including all the necessary headers (in your case `<stdio.h>` `<stdlib.h>` and `<string.h>`)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll make changes right now!

Comment: Well... I copy paste your code in VS2008, built it and run it... and guess what? It works. I think thiere is something you did you are not telling us (like having GetString function declared in a Dll ?)

Comment: @Kek No, I didn't. I told you as it was in that morning. I don't doubt it has to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're not including the required headers, which means your code could be interpreted differently by different compilers. You should add:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to make `malloc()` a well-defined function.

You're also calling `strcpy()`, so you need:

```
#include <string.h>
```

and doing I/O, for which you need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Also, in C this:

```
char *s = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX);
```

is better written as:

```
char *s = malloc(MAX);
```

since

1. It's [a bad idea to cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)
2. `sizeof (char)` is always 1, so it just adds clutter.

Finally, you should of course check that `malloc()` succeeds before using the returned pointer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't copy all code from the file. And I can't mark this as an answer either. Because it's a simplest example I could think off. Also if you will not cast malloc in VS it will show you an error! 1 IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

Comment: Moreover, if malloc will fail, it will return NULL anyway. And the s -variable in the method will be NULL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788803/what-if-malloc-fails So, yes, I have a potentional risk everything will blow up. But there was a bit different question.

Comment: @user1415536: You're trying to compile it as C++ aren't you? Try compiling it as C instead, since you know, it is C.

Comment: @netcoder it will work in Linux(gcc will not show any exeptions or warnings). I've already tried it.

Comment: @netcoder: this seems to be a [known issue in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3143815/69809), even in VS2015; intellisense treats C files as C++, so even if the source actually compiles without warnings, it will sometimes show a bunch of errors.